# Smaller images have almost no consequences on inference time in OpenCV for a Mask RCNN model

Tags: c++, tensorflow, opencv, object-detection-api

**CONTEXT**

I trained a custom MASK RCNN using Tensorflow Object Detection API to detect areas on the face. My input images are 480x480 but I chose to resize them to 240x240 so that the training can be quicker.

**MY ISSUE**

I did the inference in C++ on several computer using OpenCV DNN in another project and I have very different speed results (each computer are very different so nothing to be concerned about so far, again the predictions are good) but I have an inference time of around 2.5 seconds on the worst one (no GPU) which is too long for my purpose.

**WHAT I DID**

I trained another time my MASK RCNN model using this time 120x120 images as input. The training went around 3 times faster and the results are good enough (performing around 7% worst than the first one which is okay for me).

**PROBLEM**

When running the inference with OpenCV the inference is only less than 10ms faster (~2.5s total time) when in my opinion it should be much faster seeing how fast the training was.

**QUESTION**

I am feeding my network with a blob created such as :

```
  blob = cv::dnn::blobFromImage(image, 1.0, cv::Size(blob_height, blob_width), cv::Scalar(), true, false);
```

with `blob_height` and `blob_width` being 120 or 240 depending on the model and my image is a cv::Mat of size (480,480).
I am wondering if there is an explanation why there is so few improvement between the two models. Is the function blobFromImage return a tensor with the same kind shape as the input image or something?
I'd appreciate any help helping me to understand this or providing tips to fasten the process!

*Other infos:*

Tensorflow 1.14, OpenCV 4.4.0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To people who might have the same problems, the MASK RCNN and other models similar like Faster RCNN have always the same number of parameters regardless of the input size of the image which makes the inference time almost always the same. It is then difficult to improve inference with OpenCV.

The best solution is then to use OpenVINO toolkit (https://docs.openvinotoolkit.org/latest/index.html) which have modules to Optimize your Model (use FP16 or INT8 instead of FP32 for instance) and an inference engine optimizing the inference on the hardware specified (it however has to be an Intel hardware but for CPU it is convenient so far).

The inference is now up to 4 times faster on a CPU with OpenVINO using FP32 as in OpenCV and it is a bit trickier to use than OpenCV but definitely worth it.

Comment: This seems rather obvious. MASK RCNN is a deep model (many layers). Changing only the input resolution alters the first layer, in this case by 75%. Switching to INT8 shrinks **all** layers by 75%. You probably should check FP/FN rates.

Comment: My points was mostly to say that OpenVINO with the same precision is much faster, I didn't try with INT8 or FP16 sorry if it wasn't clear.